# Using callbacks in a Restangular service

Tags: javascript, angular.js, callback, rest

I have a project built with AngularJS and using Restangular in my services to handle API requests. The problem is I haven't found a good way to test the services which I think has turned into a bit of a code smell for me. I'm using callbacks in the promise to handle pushing the data back to the controller instead of just returning the result.

Here is a simple controller and service:

```
myApp.controller('CustomerController', ['$scope', 'Teams', function($scope, Teams) {
    Teams.getList(function(results) {
        $scope.teams = result;
    });
}]);
myApp.factory('Teams', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
    var Teams = {};
    Teams.getList = function(callback) {
        Restangular.all('teams').getList().then(function(results) {
            callback(results);
        });
    };
    return Teams;
}]);
```

Is that really the best way to get the data back to the controller? I'm starting to feel like this isn't the correct way to do it but I haven't found another way that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, when you're already using promises you also just return that instead of using a callback.  Then you can also chain more promises at the end and add error handling.  Other than that it looks fine; I don't see what you'd really change there.

```
myApp.controller('CustomerController', ['$scope', 'Teams', function($scope, Teams) {
    Teams.getList().then(function(results) {
        $scope.teams = result;
    }, function(error) {
        ...
    });
}]);
myApp.factory('Teams', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
    var Teams = {};
    Teams.getList = function() {
        return Restangular.all('teams').getList();
    };
    return Teams;
}]);
```

If you want to get rid of `Teams`, I've seen this variant as well:

```
myApp.factory('Teams', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
    var getList = function() {
        return Restangular.all('teams').getList();
    };

    return {
        getList: getList
    };
}]);
```

Comment: So you don't see an issue with the way the service is setup? The fact that `Teams` doesn't really seem to return anything has been bugging me but I wasn't sure why since there doesn't seem to be any advantage to changing. Also, the point about error handling is good.

Comment: No, not really. I mean you won't get around the async call, so there are only so many ways to do this. I'm adding a slight rewrite, but that's just stylistic.